# Load Balancer not able to connect with backend

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I have deployed the Spring boot app on the OCI compute and its comping up nicely. Compute is created with public ip and have the security list updated to allow connections from internet. But, I wasn't able to hit the end point from internet. For that reason, I thought of configuring the load balancer.

[image]

Created load balancer in a separate subnet(10.0.1.0/24), routing table and security list. Configured the LB's security list to send all protocol packets to compute's CIDR(10.0.0.0/24) and configured compute's security list to accept the packets from LB. I was expecting LB to make connection with back end. But, its not.

[image]

I am able to hit the LB from internet :-

[image]

Lb's routing table with all ips routed through internet gateway. There is no routing defined for compute's CIDR as its in the VCN.

[image]

LB has its own security list, which has allowed out going packets to compute and incoming from internet as below:

[image]
[image]

Compute's security list accepting packet's from LB:
[image]
[image]

Let me know, if I am missing something here.

My internet gateway :-
[image]

My backend set connection configuration from LB:

[image]

LB fails to make connection with backend, there seems to be no logging info available :

[image]

App is working fine , if I access from the compute node :

[image]

Comment: Did you create an Internet Gateway and set the Route Table accordingly?

Comment: yep. I have updated the screenshots. I am able to hit the LB from internet. But as LB isn't able to talk to backends, it responds with 502. Is there a explicit routing needed within  VCN ? My LB is in a subnet with cidr 10.0.1.0/24 and copute's subnet has assigned cidr 10.0.0.0/24

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The LB has a health check that tests the connection to your service.  If it fails, the LB will keep your backend out of rotation and give you the critical health like you're seeing.

[image: Default health check]

You can get to it by looking at the backend set and clicking the Update Health Check button.

[image: Backend Set configuration screen]

Edit:
Ultimately I figured it out, you should run the following commands on your backend:

```
sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=8080/tcp
sudo firewall-cmd --reload
```

Use the port that you configured your app to listen on.

I used httpd instead of spring, but I also did the following

```
sudo semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_content_t "/var/www/html(/.*)?"
sudo restorecon -F -R -v /var/www/html
```

I'm not really too familiar with selinux but you may need to do something similar for your application.

Additionally, setting up a second host in the same subnet to login to and test connecting to the other host will help troubleshooting, since it will verify if your app is accessible at all outside the host that it's on.  Once it is, the LB should come up fine.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I already have the correct backend connection info for LB to make a health check call. I dont know, what is causing LB connection request to fail at the backend.

Comment: I have added more screenshots

Comment: I am able to hit the app's end point from the compute and its working fine. I suspect network configuration for LB backend connectivity issue.

Comment: Hi @SubraM, it's likely network configuration like you said.  Are you using the same security list for both the LB subnet and the compute subnet?

Comment: Hi @juss LB has its own security list. I have updated the screenshots for both LB and compute

Comment: I messed around with it myself and figured it out.  For me, selinux was enabled on the host as well as the firewall.  So connecting via localhost was find but I couldn't connect from another endpoint.  Let me edit the answer to reflect that.

Comment: After executing firewall commands from backend, LB is able to make a connection with backend. Thank you so much @juss

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR In my case it helped to switch the Security List rules from **stateful** to **stateless** on the 2 relevant subnets (where the loadbalancer was hosted and where the backends were located).

In our deployment I had a loadbalancer with public IP located on one subnet, while the backend to this loadbalancer was on another subnet. Both subnets had one ingress and one egress rule - to allow everything (i.e. `0.0.0.0/0` and all ports allowed). The backends were still not reachable from the loadbalancer and the healthchecks were failing.

Even despite the fact that in my case as per the [documentation](https://docs.cloud.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/Network/Concepts/securityrules.htm#stateful) switching between stateful and stateless should not have an effect, it solved my issue.